# Apache2.2 won't start after install intl and icu

Tags: linux, apache, centos, icu, intl

Good day!

I have Centos 5.0 where there was need to install ICU 4.0 or higher to install intl extension. System has had ICU 3.6 so I've searched a way to do this. 
Followed by this post http://www.orocrm.com/forums/topic/centos-6-4-icu-installation-via-compilation I intalled intl extension but than got an error while trying to start Apache:

> Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 10 of
>   /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-directories.conf: Invalid command 'Order',
>   perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server
>   configuration

So we see that some module isn't enabled in httpd.conf. But which? May there is some command to see what module isn't enabled in conf?
Instruction that I followed:

```
As root:
# We start to uninstall default php-intl wich is compiled with ICU 42 (need at least 49)
yum remove php-intl
yum -y install php-devel php-pear
cd /root
mkdir src
cd src
# Download icu4c source 
wget http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/51.2/icu4c-51_2-src.tgz
tar zxf icu4c-51_2-src.tgz
cd icu/source
# Compiling and installing in /opt/icu5c-51_2 folder
./configure --prefix=/opt/icu5c-51_2 && make && make install
# Compiling PHP intl extension via pecl
pecl install intl
downloading intl-2.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download intl-2.0.1.tgz (149,430 bytes)
.................................done: 149,430 bytes
111 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] : /opt/icu5c-51_2
# Create icu.conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ with the content:
/opt/icu5c-51_2/lib/
# Run
ldconfig
# Edit /etc/php.ini add ~ line 937 the line
extension=intl.so
#Then restart apache
service httpd restart
```

Comment: Did you include the module in httpd.conf?

Comment: This is exactly my question, what module to include? Because intl and icu like I see are php extensions.

Comment: I think intl depends on ICU, I don't think icu is a php extension itself.